# Using translation on the fly for System Tray and QAction (QT)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, multilingual

I'm facing an issue regarding the translation of a system tray application that has a menu created from QAction objects.
The QAction objects only display different text based on the main applications state (wrong login credentials ... and so on), so this text changes in the lifetime of the application.
The issue is how can I use a dynamic translate for the text at a given time (when the user changes the language from GUI). The sending and receiving mechanism for the language change is in place, the load for the new translator is made in the sys tray application. (for GUI is made in the GUI application and caught based on the translation event, so it's done dynamically).

This is the loading code for the translator:

```
void Application::_SetLanguage(QString language)
{
    QTranslator *qtTranslator = new QTranslator();

    if ( qtTranslator->load( "qt_" + language, m_sExecutableDir + "/lang" ) ) {
        if ( m_qtTranslator ) {
            removeTranslator( m_qtTranslator );
            delete m_qtTranslator;
        }
        m_qtTranslator = qtTranslator;
        installTranslator(qtTranslator);
    }

    QTranslator *trayTranslator = new QTranslator();
    if ( trayTranslator->load( "ff_" + language, m_sExecutableDir + "/lang" ) ) {

        if ( m_appTranslator ) {
            removeTranslator( m_appTranslator );
            delete m_appTranslator;
//          _restartApp();
        }

        m_appTranslator = trayTranslator;
        installTranslator( trayTranslator );
    }
    emit changeLangInTray();
}
```

Here is the code for the signal:

```
ENSURE(connect(this, SIGNAL(changeLangInTray()), &m_tray, SLOT(_ChangeLanguage())));
```

And the _ChangeLanguage method, from Tray, should do the translation for it's objects:

```
QMenu               m_trayMenu;
QSystemTrayIcon     m_trayIcon;
QAction*    m_pOpenGuiAction;
.................
```

Any help is welcomed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've corrected the issue by replacing each text based on the application status when a language change is triggered.

```
void _ChangeLanguage() {
    m_pOpenGuiAction->setText(Helper::getTextOpenGui(trayStatus));
    ......
}
```

The `ui->retranslateUi(this)` is only possible if the dialog is created via QTCreator (designer), then this method, it's automatically added in the ui_*.h file.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the translator on the application object by :

```
qApp->installTranslator( qtTranslator );
```

Also`retranslateUi` should be called after you install the translator :

```
ui->retranslateUi(this);
```

For the system tray menu you can use `QCoreApplication::translate` to translate each action. Something like :

```
m_pOpenGuiAction->setText(QApplication::translate("TrayClass", "Text to translate", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
```

Comment: This is what I've used for the GUI part, but for the system tray application I don't have something like this, there is no ui_*.h for it, where you can find the retranslateUi method.
+ the tray app doesn't inherit from QWidget.
Is there something to force each QAction to take the new loaded dictionary ?

Comment: @Bogdan You can use `QCoreApplication::translate` to return the translation text of the actions and set their text. I have updated the answer.

Comment: They are using it, but after loading the new translator, the language won't change until I start the application (but then it loads the normal qtTranslator):
'status_str = QCoreApplication::translate("TrayMenu","Account: Not logged in");'

Comment: I've corrected the issue by replacing each text based on the application status when a language change is triggered. 
The ui->retranslateUi(this) is only possible if the dialog is created via QTCreator (designer), then it's automatically build.